# Makefile static lib

Tags: c, makefile, compilation, static

I have Makefile  to compile hellomake.o hellofunc.o to execute file

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I.

hellomake: hellomake.o hellofunc.o
     $(CC) -o hellomake hellomake.o hellofunc.o
```

What should I do to compile those files to 1   static library`libhellomake.a` file and not executed file?

Comment: Note though that it doesn't really make sense to have an object that contains `main` as part of a static library.

Comment: @kaylum so I will remove the `main` function..